# Trying to update Google Sheets Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to update a Google Sheets Addon.

I currently face 2 problems:

- the new Script Editor does not know anything about versions (so I used the legacy editor and created a new version there)
- when I want to deploy the changes (via the  G Suite Marketplace SDK) I get an "Project Key is not associated with the current project or the script version doesn't exist." error when I enter the new version.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't update Google Sheets addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401151/cant-update-google-sheets-addon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have just rolled back to a previous version, can you refresh and try again? Please let me know how it goes.