# Can't update Google Sheets addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have published a Google Sheet addon to the Google Workplace Marketplace. Now I'm trying to update it. After deploying a new version (Version 26 in this case), I tried to update it on the Google Workplace Marketplace SDK, but it should the following error message:

`Project Key is not associated with the current project or the script version doesn't exist.`
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfrpn.png)

Place note that I used the same method and successfully updated the addon many times, but I just cannot do it today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It looks like what you are experiencing might in fact be a bug.

This has already been reported on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187185010). I suggest you star (★) the issue and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it, as all the updates will be posted there.